# How to solve forbidden error when creating objects?

Tags: weaviate

I am using python client to create object

```py
json_data = {
    "class": class_name,
    "properties": {"text": text},
}

r = requests.post(WEAVIATE_HOST + "/v1/objects", json=json_data)
```

Most of the data works well, but some data reports forbidden error

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>403 Forbidden</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <center>
            <h1>403 Forbidden</h1>
        </center>
        <center>
            <p>Your last request has been blocked for security purposes. Please contact Web administrator with TOP_EVENTID: <907553> for detail reasons.</p>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

No relevant searches in the Document.

What is the meaning of `TOP_EVENTID: <907553>`?

How to solve this problem?

Comment: It's a limitation of the departure network firewall, not a weaviate problem.